# Can't login to mongo using root password after installing from helm

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I installed mongodb on kubernetes using helm:

```
helm install mongo bitnami/mongodb
```

now i'm trying to connect using the root password I got using this command

```
# kubectl get secret --namespace default mongo-mongodb -o jsonpath="{.data.mongodb-root-pa
ssword}" | base64 --decode
AXMCSkdNm6
```

using the root password, with the user root, i can't login. I get Authentication Failed error. trying in my mongodb desktop client, also tried inside of mongo pod:

```
$ mongo admin --username root --password AXMCSkdNm6
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**:

I managed to reproduce it always on clean install of k8s/helm:

1. install mongo the first time - authentication works perfectly
2. delete mongo via `helm delete mongo`
3. install mongo now - authentication fails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I found out the issue after a very long time...

MongoDB authentication stopped working after I deleted the release and created a new release. The reason was that I used the same persistent storage for both releases. So, when I deleted the first release the data was not deleted, and when I started a new release, it got confused, since it used the old data from the previous release...

When I delete all the data in the persistent storage when deleting the release - everything worked correctly.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Use below command. Please note `--authenticationDatabase admin` part

```
mongo admin --host "mongo-mongodb" --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p AXMCSkdNm6
```

`authenticationDatabase` specifies the authentication database where the specified `--username` has been created

Comment: no, even after adding `--authenticationDatabase admin` i get "Athentication Failes"

Comment: Worked for me without `admin --host "mongo-mongodb"`.